# connect to remote postgres database using pylons and psycopg2

Tags: pylons, psycopg2

I am able to connect to my remote database using psycopg2 in standalone Python 2.6 program, but cannot establish connection from within controller in Pylons.

How can I do that?

EDIT: exception value I am getting is **could not translate host name "localhost:7780" to address: Name or service not known**

I am creating ssh tunnel to connect to remote database.

Comment: Okay, got it working. Instead of writing port='7780' I wrote 'localhost:7780'. Shame on me...

Comment: Since you got it working, you may want to post your own answer here and accept it, so that other people know that the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved by changing url format from

`"host='localhost:7780' dbname='mydb' user='me' password='mypassword'"` to

`"host='localhost' port='7780' dbname='mydb' user='me' password='mypassword'"`.

Answer (score 1):

Set your **Database** settings like this.

```
 host='localhost' 
 port='7780' 
 dbname='mydatabase' 
 user='myusername' 
 password='mypassword'
```

Your **error** is just coming due to this setting `host='localhost:7780'`